# Problem with comparing dates - NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios4, comparison, nsdate

```
OLD DATE: 2011-04-06 10:58:43 +0000
NEW DATE: 2011-04-06 10:58:43 +0000
```

I need to compare this two dates. When new greater than old this is important for me. But I have problem my code always get in that compare code block. So above date examples is different by my application but they are same, I don't understand how I get wrong result here. This is the code:

```
Something *existing;

for(existing in exisingDatabaseItems)
{
    Something *newFromWebService;

    for(newFromWebService in WSArray)
    {
        if(existing.SomethingId == newFromWebService.SomethingId)
        {
            if([existing.LastModifiedOnDate compare:newFromWebService.LastModifiedOnDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
            {
                // It always get in here???                        
                NSLog(@"OLD: %@", existing.LastModifiedOnDate);
                NSLog(@"NEW: %@", newFromWebService.LastModifiedOnDate);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code going into the block, if you set one of the dates before to the other value? For example: `existing.LastModifiedOnDate = newFromWebService.LastModifiedOnDate`?

Comment: Both list are filled with all data. Then I compare item by item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure those dates don't have millisecond components; your logging is not showing a full UTC.

Comment: I watch variables ind debugger and there is no milliseconds. I got date from web service with milliseconds but I format that date before I store it in object. Both dates are formated in the same way.

Comment: What do you get if you call... - (BOOL)isEqualToDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate

Comment: Ok for both what is the value (NSTimeInterval) of - (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSince1970

Comment: this one is from web service 4.9406564584124654e-324
this one is from database = 1302087523
This is how I got this: double s = [existing.LastModifiedOnDate timeIntervalSince1970];   
                double e = [newFromWebService.LastModifiedOnDate timeIntervalSince1970];

Comment: I found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954668/need-advise-about-compare-nsdate